# Copying selective columns data till data in column 1 ends

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently using the following code to copy paste data from File- "Source" to File-"Destination". It is selecting the rows till data ends in Column-1.
However, currently all the columns from **A** to **AE** are selected, but instead I want selective columns like **A,F,K,AA** to be selected.
I understand that the code in "wb.ActiveSheet.Range("A2:AE" & N).Copy" needs to be changed but not sure of the syntax.
Can anyone help me with this? Appreciate the help in advance.

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

Dim N As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
N = Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown).Row
wb.ActiveSheet.Range("A2:AE" & N).Copy

Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Desktop\Destination.xlsx")

y.Activate
y.Sheets("Data").Select
y.Sheets("Data").Activate


For Each Cell In y.Sheets("Data").Columns(1).Cells
     If Len(Cell) = 0 Then Cell.Select: Exit For
Next Cell
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.Close True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Application.Union` to combine ranges from different columns (from row 2 until `N`).

Also, instead of looping through your `y.Sheets("Data").Columns(1).Cells` to find the empty `Cell`, you can just use  `LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1`.

I added 2 `With wb.Sheets("Sheet1")` to fully qualify all variables and `Range` nested underneath.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyColumns()

Dim wb      As Workbook
Dim Y       As Workbook
Dim N       As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim CopyRng As range

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

' you need to specify the sheet, otherwise it will take the Active Sheet
With wb.Sheets("Sheet1") ' <-- modify to your sheet's name
    N = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' <-- get last row from Column "A", skips blank cells in te middle
    ' set the range to Columns A, F, K, AA
    Set CopyRng = Application.Union(.Range("A2:A" & N), .Range("F2:F" & N), .Range("K2:K" & N), .Range("AA2:AA" & N))
End With

Set Y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Desktop\Destination.xlsx")    
With Y.Sheets("Data")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1 '<-- get first empty row at Column A to paste at
    CopyRng.Copy
    .Range("A" & LastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End With    
Y.Close True

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```